# Avoid logs full of java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Server-Sent events on one browser, and a spring boot application on the back end. When I shot down the client, I get the next exception:

```
14:35:09.458 [http-nio-8084-exec-25] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost] - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

I understand this is the expected behavior; on the other hand, my application works fine, but I have awful logs full of those exceptions. I guess this is caused by Tomcat. Is there a way to catch these exceptions, or at least to prevent Tomcat from writing this exception stack trace to the log? I mean, without modifying Tomcat's code.

Comment: How is your logging configured?

Comment: Is this relevant? I want everything logged except this exception. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: Of course it's relevant. You have a question about logging, and you won't even tell you how your logging is configured? Which logging framework are you using? Where are you seeing the logged lines above, `catalina.out`?

Comment: As I said, I want every exception logged but this, wherever they come from. Logging framework: SLF4J

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this exception in logs you can try some changes in your code that performs push on client. Here is my example. I listen to api called and then it called I push socket to the client. I think you could understand the code:

```
 @GetMapping("/api/status/{groupId}/{groupstatusId}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
public void listenToNewStatus(@PathVariable Long groupId, @PathVariable String groupstatusId, IOException e) {
    Group group = groupDTOService.findById(groupId);
    if (group != null) {
        if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e), "Broken pipe")) {
            logger.info("broken pipe");
        } else {
            template.convertAndSend("/topic/callstatus/" + group.getUser().getId(), groupstatusId);
        }

    }
```

In this code to prevent broken pipe I add annotation @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class) and check if exception contains broken pipe then nothing else send message to client.